# Gradle / Maven difference in treating version range

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I'm using the [QR-Bill library v2.5.3](https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.codecrete.qrbill/qrbill-generator/2.5.3/jar). As one of its dependencies, it specifies PDFBox using the range `[2.0.0,3.0)`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>[2.0.0,3.0)</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

With a Gradle project, the dependency resolves to `pdfbox-2.0.24`. With a Maven project, it resolves to `pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1`.

Do Maven and Gradle really treat version ranges differently? What would the correct range be for the library so that both Gradle and Maven use the latest 2.x version of PDFBox but do not use version 3.x (as it is incompatible)?

Further debugging details:

**Maven Project**

https://github.com/manuelbl/SwissQRBill/tree/master/examples/maven_example

```
% mvn dependency:tree

[INFO] net.codecrete.qrbill:maven-example:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- net.codecrete.qrbill:qrbill-generator:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO]    +- io.nayuki:qrcodegen:jar:1.7.0:runtime (version selected from constraint [1.6.0,2.0))
[INFO]    \- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:3.0.0-RC1:runtime (version selected from constraint [2.0.0,3.0))
[INFO]       +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:3.0.0-RC1:runtime
[INFO]       \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:runtime
```

**Gradle project**

https://github.com/manuelbl/SwissQRBill/tree/master/examples/gradle_example

```
% gradle dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
\--- net.codecrete.qrbill:qrbill-generator:2.5.3+ -> 2.5.3
     +--- io.nayuki:qrcodegen:[1.6.0,2.0) -> 1.7.0
     \--- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:[2.0.0,3.0) -> 2.0.24
          +--- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:2.0.24
          |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
          \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
```

Comment: That's weird. Definitely looks like a Maven bug. Report it, and they might acknowledge it before 2030.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Maven's ordering implementation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Version_Order_Specification) states than alpha, beta, and RC versions are lesser that an actual release. This is why you see this behavior happening.

So, in practice pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1 < pdfbox-3.0.

In order to exclude 3.0 completely you need to exclude the first pre-release. Some ways you can achieve that:

[2.0.,3-alpha)

[2.0.0,3.0.0-alpha2)

Or another option -which is not ideal- is to specify the upper-bound of the range as the latest revision of the 2.x release:

[2.0.0,2.0.24]

This last option is far from great because if Apache releases a revision of 2.x named 2.0.25, Maven wont include it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's well-document but still surprising that there is no way to specify the intention of `2.*` easily. And even more surprising is that Gradle seems to have the same [version ordering definition](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html#version_ordering) yet treats it differently.

Comment: @Codo, yep, one would expect it to be easier to exclude a major version completely. While it does make sense from the strict ordering POV, conceptually, if you want to exclude 3.x, why would you want to accept alpha version of it? Guess Apache aimed for flexibility (? Who knows... Anyway, glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Based upon Diego M.'s answer, here is some additional information:

The version requirement `[2.0,3.0)` does not seem to ever make sense:

- The typical intention is to restrict it to all 2.* version. However, Maven also includes all 3.0 pre-release version. I cannot imagine a case where this would be useful.
- Maven and Gradle interpret it differently. So it is not suitable whenever both tools are used, in particular when publishing to Maven Central.

The better version requirement for restricting to 2.* versions is: `[2.0,2.999999]`.